# Нужна ли точка с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, точка-с-запятой

Уместна ли точка с запятой и правильно ли составлен текст?

```
Клятвы разрушены временем,
Чувства растоптаны сволочью,
Чрево испачкано семенем,
Мысли наполнены горечью.
Сердце, разбитое вдребезги,
Бывшее плотью и мякотью,
Ныне, покрытое плесенью,
Злостно забытое памятью,
Тлеет остатками верности
К мразной бесчувственной сволочи(;)
Вместо интима и нежности -
Тихие порции горечи.
```

Comment: @Отто Фурнхайм, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Текст состоит из трёх разных по структуре, но строго организованных внутри предложений.

Первое - БСП с четырьмя параллельными простыми предложениями в составе.

Второе - простое, осложнённое четырьмя обособленными распространёнными определениями, относящимися к слову СЕРДЦЕ. После него нужна **точка.** Она завершает объёмную конструкцию осложнённого предложения и придаёт этому предложению форму.

Третье предложение - простое с обособленным дополнением, по смыслу это итог, следствие из всего сказанного выше. Так что его лучше оформить как отдельное предложение.

Точка с запятой допустима, но лучше всё-таки поставить точку.

Answer (score 1):

Указанная точка с запятой возможна.

Дополнение

Точка с запятой обусловлена тем, что это БСП.  Постановка точки будет обозначать законченное предложение, т.е. "Вместо интима и нежности -Тихие порции горечи" не связано со вторым предложением. Если же вчитаться в предложение лучше, то оно все же связано со вторым, т.к. является БСП.
Однако если возможно точка с запятой, но здесь все же лучше поставить тире, поскольку последняя часть имеет результативно-разъясняющий характер относительно первой части.

> Я задал этот вопрос ( о возможности постановки точки запятой или тире). Привожу ответ справочной службы Грамма.ру.
>
> ***Фраза, которую Вы приводите, является сложным бессоюзным предложением. В составе бессоюзного сложного предложения употребление точки с запятой возможно, однако для постановки этого знака препинания необходимо, чтобы части предложения были самостоятельны. В Вашем примере последняя часть ("Вместо интима и нежности, / Тихие порции горечи") имеет результативно-разъясняющий характер относительно первой части. В этом случае более нормативным является употребление тире. См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2009. С. 259-264.
> Более правильным с пунктуационной точки зрения будет такое оформление фразы:
> Сердце, разбитое вдребезги,
> Бывшее плотью и мякотью,
> Ныне, покрытое плесенью,
> Злостно забытое памятью,
> Тлеет остатками верности
> К мразной бесчувственной сволочи -
> Вместо интима и нежности(,)
> Тихие порции горечи.***

***Запятая после оборота с предлогом "вместо" является факультативной.***

Comment: Благодарю.

Comment: @Серж, Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 0):

Знак точка с запятой не обусловлен, так-как здесь сплошной ряд перечислений взаимообусловленных подлежащих и сказуемых (иногда подразумеваемых), характеризующих состояние единого объекта. Так что - запятая.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с EkaterinaKas...

1. Решением задачки может стать признание фразы (до искомого знака) громоздкой и требующей полной остановки, - точки.
2. Деление сложного предложения при столь неравных по массе простых - не приходилось встречать. Различны они и по своему строю.
3. Точка с запятой вообще - прозаический знак, странно видеть его в поэтической строке; коль скоро не нравится точка, есть вариант - двоеточие.